# Entity Framework - Programmatically generating and updating model for whole database?

Tags: entity-framework

It seems like Stored Procedures must be added and updated manually through the GUI.  I'm looking to have this done programmatically.  The longterm goal is to ensure any changes in the Stored Procedure names and signatures (parameters) made directly in the database and then updating the EF model will require any calling code to be updated to match or give a compile time error if not.

A year and a few Entity Framework versions have passed.  Is something like this possible now?